# Round-Robin between Customers

Tags: postgresql, django-rest-framework

So here is the deal...

Assume that you have multiple clients that sell their items at different prices. As the owner, you decided to give a fair chance to every client that uses your platform. Therefore, you need some sort of a way to fill the purchase orders between the sellers in such a way that everyone gets their items sold.

Round-Robin like method is required! So for example here is a way to describe the data:

```
Ohad, items: 5, price: 1$
Daniel, items: 2, price: 1$
Jim, items: 3, price: 1$
Tim, items: 1, price: 1.05$
```

If a client wishes to buy 4 items in Bulk, he should receive the items of Ohad -> Daniel -> Jim -> Ohad
(And the next time a bulk purchase will be executed, Daniel would start the lead)

If the client wishes to buy 11 items, first it will go around the people that share the same lowest price, and then it will add Tim's on top to match the requirement of 11 total items.

And of course, if the list of sellers was longer, the round-robin principles should still exist.

---

I am trying to think about an efficient way to get this done... I find most solutions to be very consuming or not 1000% working.
seriously don't want to limit people with their ideas... so I would love to hear anything and we will take it from there! :/

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and don't make it more complicated than necessary.

Let the law of large numbers work for you and randomly pick a seller for each order you get, then fill the whole order from that seller. If there are enough orders and you use a good enough random number generator (`random()` should do), it will even out in time.

This will ignore price differences, so maybe you could use

```
ORDER BY random() * price LIMIT 1
```

to pick the seller to serve an order.

Comment: I guess that it is the proper way to go about it. most likely the user experience would still be relatively good (when it comes to sales) and no extra logic required that will slow the process down.